# Display 0 when count(*) is zero for a group by clause

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to write a SQL query which can display value as 0 if there are no rows for the specified condition

I have tried the following so far but nothing seems to work

1. `coalesce(count(m.a),'0')`
2. `isnull(count(m.a),'0')`
3. `case when count(*) > 0 then count(*) else '0' end`

```
select  M.a, m.b, m.c, m.d, m.e,
 --coalesce(count(m.a),'0') as CountOfRecords
 --isnull(count(m.a),'0') as CountOfRecords
 --case when count(*) > 0 then count(*) else '0' end
 from my_table M
 left join

 (select a, b,c,d,e 
  from my_table
 group by a, b,c,d,e 
 having count(*) >1 ) B
 on M.b = B.b 
 and M.c = B.c
 and M.d = B.d
 and M.e = B.e
 and m.a <> B.a

 where M.a in (1,2)
 and M.date<= '1/1/2019'
 group by M.a, m.b, m.c, m.d, m.e
```

Expected Result

```
A  B  C  D E  count
1  1  1  1 1   10
2  2  2  2 2   0
```

Actual Result

```
A  B  C  D E  count
1  1  1  1 1   10
```

Comment: Could you add here a minimum number of example rows of `my_table` to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a nested request:

```
select coalesce(nb, 0) from (
  select count(*) nb from my_table
  group by my_table.a
) nested;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select a, b, c, d, e,
       sum(case when M.date <= '2019-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from my_table
where a in (1, 2)
group by a, b, c, d, e;
```

This keeps all rows in the original data that match the condition on `a`, but not necessarily the condition on the date.  It then counts only the rows that match the date.

Comment: thanks! But I want -  if for a particular values of a,b,c,d,e and m.date <='01/01/2019' there are no rows in the table then 0 is displayed. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @TigSh . . . That is utterly unclear from your question, which does not mention specific values that have to be in the result set.